# Which groups have undetectable third U(1)-cohomology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group. A *categorical Schur detector* for $G$ is a set $\mathcal{S}$ of proper subgroups $S \subsetneq G$ such that the total restriction map
$$ \mathrm{rest}_{\mathcal{S}} : \mathrm{H}^3(G; \mathrm{U}(1)) \to \prod_{S \in \mathcal{S}} \mathrm{H}^3(S; \mathrm{U}(1)) $$
is an injection. The name is a riff on the suggestion of Epa and Ganter to call $\mathrm{H}_3(G;\mathbb{Z})$ the *categorical Schur multiplier* of $G$ ([Platonic and alternating 2-groups, *Higher Structures* 1(1):122–146, 2017](https://journals.mq.edu.au/index.php/higher_structures/article/view/30)).

I know of two classes of groups which do not admit categorical Schur detectors: the cyclic and the binary dihedral (aka dicyclic) groups of prime power order. (Of course, a binary dihedral group of prime power order is necessarily of order $2^n$.) This follows from the fact that for any finite subgroup $G \subset \mathrm{SU}(2)$,  there is an isomorphism $\mathrm{H}^3(G;\mathrm{U}(1)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/\lvert G\rvert$.

> **Question:** Are there any other finite groups which do not admit categorical Schur detectors?

Of course, one could ask the same question about cohomology of other degrees, or with other coefficients. $\mathrm{H}^3(-;\mathrm{U}(1))$ is of particular interest in "moonshine", because it is home to global symmetry anomalies of 2D QFTs.

Comment: I record the trivial remark that a group of non-prime-power order always admits a categorical Schur detector, namely the set of its Sylow subgroups. Note that my definition of "categorical Schur detector" requires that each subgroup in the set be proper.

Comment: A variant of your question has been studied in the literature: the case when the coefficients are $\mathbb Z/p$, and the common kernel of restrictions to all proper subgroups is called essential cohomology.  Adem and Karagueuzian show that a p-group has essential cohomology if all its elements of order p are central.  (I gave a different proof, giving a degree in which this happens.)

Comment: @NicholasKuhn Thank you. I did not know the term "essential cohomology". Is the paper of you mention https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612133?

Comment: Yes.  And it appeared in Advances in 2007.

Comment: @NicholasKuhn Thanks!

Comment: what's the picture for abelian $p$-groups?

Comment: @YCor I don't know! Well, the examples I have thought about make it seem like the primes 2 and 3 each have peculiar behaviour for H^3, and there's nothing interesting in the larger primes, but I certainly don't claim this as proven fact.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by YCor's remark I realized that every finite abelian $p$-group $G$ of rank three will have essential elements in $H^3(G;U(1))$.  I think that this works for $p=2$ as well, but here's an argument for $p$ odd.  Let $y_1,y_2,y_3$ be linearly independent elements of $H^1(G;\mathbb{F}_p)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$.  If $S$ is any proper subgroup of $G$, then the image of $H^1(G;\mathbb{F}_p)\rightarrow H^1(S;\mathbb{F}_p)$ has rank two.  Thus the images of $y_1,y_2,y_3$ in $H^1(S;\mathbb{F}_p)$ are no longer linearly independent, and so the product $y_1y_2y_3$ is an element of $H^3(G;\mathbb{F}_p)$ that is essential.

It remains to show that $y_1y_2y_3$ has non-zero image under the map $H^3(G;\mathbb{F}_p)\rightarrow H^3(G;U(1))$ induced by the inclusion of additive groups $\mathbb{F}_p\rightarrow U(1)$.  For this, look at the long exact sequence in cohomology coming from the short exact coefficient sequence $0\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p\rightarrow U(1)\rightarrow U(1)\rightarrow 0$.  It suffices to show that the image of $H^2(G;U(1))\rightarrow H^3(G;\mathbb{F}_p)$ does not contain $y_1y_2y_3$.  I struggle with $U(1)$ coefficients, so I would instead show the equivalent fact that $y_1y_2y_3$ is not in the image of $H^3(G;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^3(G;\mathbb{F}_p)$.  This is because $H^3(G;\mathbb{Z})$ is detected by proper subgroups.  Roughly speaking this is because for a finite cyclic group $C$, $H^1(C;\mathbb{Z})=0$.  In terms of the Kunneth theorem, the only way to get elements in degree three for a product of cyclic groups is as a `Tor' term coming from a pair of elements of $H^2(C;\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^2(C';\mathbb{Z})$ for cyclic subgroups $C$, $C'$.  But such an element is detected on the subgroup $C\times C'$.

This should generalize: if $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group then every element of $H^{k+1}(G;\mathbb{Z})$ will be detected on subgroups of rank $k$.  If so, then for $G$ an abelian $p$-group $H^3(G;U(1))$ will contain essential elements if and only if $G$ has rank 1 or 3.